# Is it possible to create a centralized saving point of all the variables I use all throughout my program? If so, how?

Tags: java, swing

This is my first time in Stackoverflow, so forgive me for my noob post.

My friends and I have a class project to create a game. Now, we each made a portion of the game, like the Battle, MapMovement, etc. Our problem is, in order to "stitch" our separate pieces of code together, we have to keep transferring the values to and fro each "portion" of the game.

Say for example the user is exploring the map, then encounters a monster which triggers the battle, after which the user returns to the map or goes to the death screen. So the variables will have to move Map -> Battle -> Map.

I've been thinking about using interfaces or abstract classes to use as the main hub for all the variables, but I just can't think of *how* to actually do it. Any ideas?

So my portion is the map, which here is called MapFrame.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.*;


public class MapFrame implements KeyListener{
JFrame frame;
int heroLocation, level;
MapFrame(){}
MapFrame(int heroLocation, int level){
    this.heroLocation = heroLocation;
    this.level = level;
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    System.out.println(BattleFrame.variable);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(12, 12, 0, 0)); 
    JLabel l;
    for(int tile = 0; tile < 144; tile++){
        l = helper.tile_set(tile, heroLocation, level);
        panel.add(l);
    }
    frame.addKeyListener(this);
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new MapFrame(132, 1);
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {           //UP
        if(heroLocation>=0 && heroLocation <= 11){
        }else if(helper.tile_restriction(heroLocation, level, 1)){
        }else if(helper.encounter()){
            frame.dispose();
            new BattleFrameUsage(heroLocation, level, 1);
        }else{
            heroLocation -= 12;
            new MapFrame(heroLocation, level);
            frame.dispose();
        }
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {           //LEFT
        if(heroLocation%12 == 0){
        }else if(helper.tile_restriction(heroLocation, level, 2)){
        }else if(helper.encounter()){
            frame.dispose();
            new BattleFrameUsage(heroLocation, level, 2);
        }else{
            heroLocation -= 1;
            new MapFrame(heroLocation, level);
            frame.dispose();
        }
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {           //DOWN
        if(heroLocation>=132 && heroLocation<=143){
        }else if(helper.tile_restriction(heroLocation, level, 3)){
        }else if(helper.encounter()){
            frame.dispose();
            new BattleFrameUsage(heroLocation, level, 3);
        }else{
            heroLocation += 12;
            new MapFrame(heroLocation, level);
            frame.dispose();
        }
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {           //RIGHT
        if(heroLocation%12 == 11){
        }else if(helper.tile_restriction(heroLocation, level, 4)){
        }else if(helper.encounter()){
            frame.dispose();
            new BattleFrameUsage(heroLocation, level, 4);
        }else{
            heroLocation += 1;
            new MapFrame(heroLocation, level);
            frame.dispose();
        }
    }
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { }
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }
}
```

and some of my methods I put into a helper file, just to keep MapFrame.java a little bit less messy. Over here: helper.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class helper{
helper(){}
public static void main(String[] args){}
//For the tiles
public static double[] level_1 =
{
1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.2,1.2,1.2,1.2,1.2,    //1.1 is tree tile, 1.2 is fire tile
1.1,1.1,1.1,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,2.3,    //1.3 is grass tile, 1.4 is river tile
1.1,2.2,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.4,    //1.5 is bridge tile, 1.6 is bucket tile
1.1,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.4,1.4,1.5,1.5,1.4,1.4,    //2.1 is merchant god, 2.2 is portal,
1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,2.1,1.4,1.4,1.4,1.5,1.5,1.4,1.4,    //2.3 is shrine, 2.4 is atk up
1.3,1.3,1.3,1.4,1.4,1.4,1.4,1.4,1.5,1.5,1.4,1.4,    //2.5 is def up, 2.6 is agi up
1.4,1.4,1.4,1.4,1.4,1.4,1.4,1.6,1.3,1.3,1.2,2.4,
1.4,1.4,1.4,1.4,1.4,1.4,1.4,1.4,1.5,1.5,1.4,1.4,
1.4,1.4,1.4,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.4,1.4,1.5,1.5,1.4,1.4,
1.4,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.5,1.1,1.4,
1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,    //1 are general level-only tiles,
1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3     //2 are merchant god, portal, shrine
};


public static JLabel tile_set(int x, int heroLocation, int level){
    JLabel l = null;
    /*if (x == 0){
        l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("tile-grass.png"));
        return l;
    }*/
    if (x == heroLocation){
        if(level_1[x] == 1.3){
            l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("grass_char.png"));
        }else if(level_1[x] == 1.5){
            l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("bridge_char.png"));
        }else{
            l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("breakdancing cat.gif"));
        }
        return l;
    }else if(level == 1){
        if (level_1[x] == 1.1){
            l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("tree.png"));
        }else if (level_1[x] == 1.2){
            l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("fire.png"));
        }else if (level_1[x] == 1.3){
            l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("grass.png"));
        }else if (level_1[x] == 1.4){
            l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("water.png"));
        }else if (level_1[x] == 1.5){
            l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("bridge.png"));
        }else if (level_1[x] == 1.6){
            l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("bucket.png"));
        }else if (level_1[x] == 2.1){
            l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("mammon.png"));
        }else if (level_1[x] == 2.2){
            l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("portal.png"));
        }else if (level_1[x] == 2.3){
            l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("level up shrine.png"));
        }else if (level_1[x] == 2.4){
            l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("sword.png"));
        }
    }else if(level == 2){
        if (level_1[x] == 2.1){
            l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("buddypoke roundhouse jordan.gif"));
        }else if (level_1[x] == 2.2){
            l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("buddypoke roundhouse jordan.gif"));
        }else if (level_1[x] == 2.1){
            l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("mammon.png"));
        }else if (level_1[x] == 2.2){
            l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("portal.png"));
        }else if (level_1[x] == 2.3){
            l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("level up shrine.png"));
        }else if (level_1[x] == 2.4){
            l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("sword.png"));
        }
    }
return l;
}

public static int heroLocation1, move;

public static boolean level_1_restriction(){
    if(move == 1){
        if(level_1[heroLocation1-12] == 1.1 || level_1[heroLocation1-12] == 1.2 || level_1[heroLocation1-12] == 1.4 || level_1[heroLocation1-12] == 2.1 || level_1[heroLocation1-12] == 2.3){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else if (move == 2){
        if(level_1[heroLocation1-1] == 1.1 || level_1[heroLocation1-1] == 1.2 || level_1[heroLocation1-1] == 1.4 || level_1[heroLocation1-1] == 2.1 || level_1[heroLocation1-1] == 2.3){
            return true;
        }else if(level_1[heroLocation1-1] == 1.6){
            level_1[heroLocation1-1] = 1.4;
            level_1[82] = 1.3;
            return false;
        }else if(heroLocation1 == 83 && level_1[heroLocation1-1] == 1.3){
            level_1[heroLocation1-1] = 1.4;
            return false;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else if (move == 3){
        if(level_1[heroLocation1+12] == 1.1 || level_1[heroLocation1+12] == 1.2 || level_1[heroLocation1+12] == 1.4 || level_1[heroLocation1+12] == 2.1 || level_1[heroLocation1+12] == 2.3){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else if (move == 4){
        if(level_1[heroLocation1+1] == 1.1 || level_1[heroLocation1+1] == 1.2 || level_1[heroLocation1+1] == 1.4 || level_1[heroLocation1+1] == 2.1 || level_1[heroLocation1+1] == 2.3){
            return true;
        }else if(level_1[heroLocation1+1] == 2.4){
            level_1[83] = 1.4;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

/*
Movement variable legend:
1 = north
2 = west
3 = south
4 = east
*/

public static boolean tile_restriction(int heroLocation, int level, int movement){
    heroLocation1 = heroLocation;
    move = movement;
    if(level == 1){
        return level_1_restriction();
    }else if(level == 2){
    }else if(level == 3){
    }else if(level == 4){
    }else if(level == 5){
    }

    return false;
}

public static boolean encounter(){
    double chance = Math.random() * 100;
    System.out.println(chance);
    if (chance >= 0 && chance <= 25){
        //return true;
        return false;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Here is my friend's two pieces of code, the first which is the BattleFrame:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


class BattleFrame extends JFrame {
    BattleFrame () {
        //Frame
        setSize(600, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Battle Frame");
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.lightGray);


        //battlePanel buttons
        JButton buttonSkills = new JButton("Skills");
        JButton buttonItems = new JButton("Items");
        JButton buttonParty = new JButton("Party");
        JButton buttonRun = new JButton("Run");

        buttonSkills.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        buttonItems.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        buttonParty.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        buttonRun.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        //

        //battlePanel
        JPanel battlePanel = new JPanel();

        battlePanel.add(buttonSkills, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
        battlePanel.add(buttonItems, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        battlePanel.add(buttonParty, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        battlePanel.add(buttonRun, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        battlePanel.setBackground(Color.cyan.darker());
        //

        add(battlePanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setVisible(true);

        //Skills
        buttonSkills.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SkillsFrame sf = new SkillsFrame();
                dispose();
            } 
        }
        );

        //Items
        buttonItems.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ItemsFrame sf = new ItemsFrame();
                dispose();
            } 
        }
        );

        buttonRun.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //Run effect
                dispose();
            }
        }
        );
    }
}

class SkillsFrame extends JFrame {

        SkillsFrame () {

            setSize(600, 600);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setTitle("Skills Frame");
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.lightGray);


            //SkillsPanel Buttons
            JButton buttonWeakAttack = new JButton("Weak Attack");
            JButton buttonNormalAttack = new JButton("Normal Attack");
            JButton buttonPowerAttack = new JButton("Power Attack");
            JButton buttonBack = new JButton("Back");

            buttonWeakAttack.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            buttonNormalAttack.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            buttonPowerAttack.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            buttonBack.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            //

            //Skills Panel
            JPanel skillsPanel = new JPanel();

            skillsPanel.add(buttonWeakAttack, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            skillsPanel.add(buttonNormalAttack, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            skillsPanel.add(buttonPowerAttack, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            skillsPanel.add(buttonBack, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            skillsPanel.setBackground(Color.cyan.darker());
            //

            add(skillsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            setVisible(true);


            buttonWeakAttack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //Weak Attack effects
                }
            }
            );

            buttonNormalAttack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //Normal Attack effects
                }
            }
            );

            buttonPowerAttack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //Power Attack effects
                }
            }
            );

            buttonBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    BattleFrame bf = new BattleFrame();
                    dispose();
                }
            }
            );

        }
}


class ItemsFrame extends JFrame {

        ItemsFrame () { 

            setSize(600, 600);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setTitle("Skills Frame");
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.lightGray);

            JButton buttonPotion = new JButton("Potion");
            JButton buttonTeleportScroll = new JButton("Teleport Scroll");
            JButton buttonFireballScroll = new JButton("Fireball Scroll");
            //ADD MORE ITEMS IF LIKE

            buttonPotion.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            buttonTeleportScroll.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            buttonFireballScroll.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

            //ItemsPanel
            JPanel itemsPanel = new JPanel();

            itemsPanel.add(buttonPotion, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            itemsPanel.add(buttonTeleportScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            itemsPanel.add(buttonFireballScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            add(itemsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            setVisible(true);

            buttonPotion.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //Potion effects
                }
            }
            );

            buttonTeleportScroll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //Teleport Scroll effects
                }
            }
            );

            buttonFireballScroll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //Fireball Scroll Effects
                }
            }
            );
        }
}
```

and how to call it is here:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class BattleFrameUsage {
int herolocation, maplevel, direction;
    BattleFrameUsage(){}
    BattleFrameUsage(int hero, int level, int move) {
        herolocation = hero;
        maplevel = level;
        direction = move;
        new BattleFrame();
        if (direction == 1){
            herolocation -= 12;
            new MapFrame(herolocation, maplevel);
        }else if (direction == 2){
            herolocation -= 1;
            new MapFrame(herolocation, maplevel);
        }else if (direction == 3){
            herolocation += 12;
            new MapFrame(herolocation, maplevel);
        }else if (direction == 4){
            herolocation += 1;
            new MapFrame(herolocation, maplevel);
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {}
}
```

I admit that ours is rather inefficient, but we have too little time to make it as awesome as it should be. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Think maybe not in variables passing between pieces of code but instead of Objects sending Messages to each other. Who asks whom what to do? Maybe you can share some of your code so we can give some concrete advice.

Comment: Variables should always belong to their Object. For example user has a name. The name belongs to the user object, it doesnt matter if he/she is on the map or in a battle.

Comment: Okay, give me a couple of minutes to add in the current progress of our code. And @Jan, yep. That's what I'm trying to bypass to get rid of the need to send messages to each other. ThoFin, our code is, admittedly, very inefficient. You'll get to see it in a few minutes.

Comment: this maybe a way to go : http://blue-walrus.com/2013/06/mediator-pattern-in-swing/ .The media pattern sits between the modules and exposes methods which they can communicate with each other

Comment: or you could use PropertyChangeListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a pattern that matches what you're describing. It's called the [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). The basic gist behind the pattern is that only one instance of the Singleton class will ever be created, meaning that any variables you attach to it will be accessible from anywhere in your code.

**However**, it is important to point out that very often, the Singleton pattern is used when other software design principles should be applied instead. In your case, perhaps data binding or raising events would be the correct course of action. Generally speaking, you only want to create a Singleton when it's absolutely necessary - if you have a lot of Singletons (or one Singleton with a lot of variables attached), that's a good sign that your code is not structured properly.

Comment: Hmm - maybe applying MVC first would make most of the issues go away?

Comment: I checked this Singleton pattern, and it seems to be good way to start on this. Thanks, Mage Xy.

Comment: @AndrewDagdag Take a look at Jan's answer and see if you can implement the MVC pattern. MVC is used in a lot of game programs due to it's flexible nature. A Singleton, while convenient, eventually leads to bad code if you don't know why you're using it. (It's basically a glorified global variable.)

Comment: @MageXy I can see how a Singleton, or a lot of Singletons (which is what will probably happen to me), take a lot of useless space and bloat. I just looked at the MVC pattern, and it's definitely a lot more efficient than a Singleton. However, to adjust and reconfigure our code to fit the MVC is something I will most likely have trouble with doing in the limited amount of time left. The Singleton, on the other hand, is easier to handle. I will keep in mind to use the MVC, and other, patterns on future projects.

Answer (score 2):

As answered before, you could use a Singleton to hold together all your game data and then switch from frame to frame presenting different views rendered from variables pulled from that singleton.

But.

There's another pattern that you might want to learn about. It's called [Model-View-Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

The basic concept here is to abstract the *model* (the data, in your case: The game-information) from the *view* (how it's displayed, your game screens) and the *controller* (how you can interact with the views and what that does with the model)

In your case a view would be the map-frame. The map frame accesses the model (TheGame) to render the hero's position (which it retrieves from TheGame by invoking a `getHeroPosition()` method)

You MapFrame's KeyListeners are part of the controller - they interface between the model (TheGame) and the view. If the controller would receive a click on the "down" button, it would invoke a method 'goSouth()' on the model and afterwards tell the view to update. Which this would do by asking the model for the Hero#s position.

If by moving south the hero would encounter a villain, the controller would instead bring up the BattleView, which would then ask the model for Hero's and Villain's characteristics...

As you're already working as a team (which is **great!**), you could take the code you have and assign one of these roles to each other.

Mage will be the view. You can *ask* the model (let's call her Molly) for information and you can *tell* the Controller (Conny) that something happend in your view.

Molly will be the model. She holds all information about who and what and where. This is kind of your "variable store" you asked about. She tells Mage where everybody is and receives updates from Conny

Conny received notifications from Mage, passed them on to Molly and tells Mage to change something.

If you get it set up in this way, your code will be more readable and easier to extend, as the roles - which class has to perform which part of the whole is much more clear.

Good luck with your game. Need a tester?

Comment: Thanks a lot for an easier explanation on the MVC model! Very helpful. Sadly, time constraints don't give us much leeway on the efficiency of our code. We haven't even finished the groundwork yet. Also, at the start of the project, we didn't even know that we needed these "patterns" (we didn't even know they existed before you guys mentioned them. Darn it.)

Well, it's actually just for our class and.. I can feel the "noob" feel of our code. It's kind of sad to look at, really. So maybe next time, if we've improved it (after the deadline and such), you could have a go at our "minigame" :)

Comment: still... you might be well off with a hybrid: Code a model - that is some Game class holding all the info and with methods that reflect actions (like `attack(Villain aVillain)`) and pass that along between your views. So each of your views gets a constructor with a Game object. And depending on what happens you create some new view and pass along your local Game to the next view

Comment: Once you decided which answer is best, you should accept one, making it clear to all yout question is resolved.